# How to exit the application (killing all the views) in android studio?

Tags: android, exit

I am currently working on making a game and I want to exit the game on exit button pressed. 
I tried using:

`finish();`

`System.exit(0);`

But its redirecting me to the main screen of the game.

I want to completely exit the game.

Answer (score 0):

finish() and System.exit(0) kills the activity not the app and I believe you want to exit from a child activity to another main activity, and there is no internal function that will stop the app, so you need to follow something like below: 
In your exit button click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ChildActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now in your MainActivity include:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mContext = getApplicationContext();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    // your current codes
    // your current codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method finishAffinity for this.

**For API below 16**

```
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this)
```

**For API above 16+ us below code:**

```
finishAffinity();
```

Use System.exit(0) for releasing the resources and exit the application.